# Small server for small company

Tags: hardware

I'm looking for some opinions about a server I'm about to buy for a small company of software development, the client is looking for something not so expensive, but I would like to make a good low-cost server choose :)

They want to use it with Linux, Apache, PHP, Subversion, MySQL and backing up propose for internal use. (not for massive access)

May you recommend me some product lines, or any experiences with similar reliable kind of server.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't mention if you want a rack-mounted or tower server but I'd be tempted to stick with something from one of the big manufacturers as I assume supportablity would be of benefit to this small team.

For a tower I'd go with either a Dell T310 or HP ML370 - both have the option for dual power supply, plenty of processor/memory/disk options, are well priced and I've good experience of them both personally.

For rack-mounted I'd go with HP's DL360 or DL380 or Dell's R310 for the same reasons as above.

Comment: Thanks @Chopper3, I was thinking in a tower server, i'll check the models you told me.

Answer (score 0):

Just buy any normal priced PC. It will do just fine. Be sure it has (at least) two harddrives so you can build a raid system in case some disk gets destroyed. All other hardware parts can be replaced quickly.

Regarding CPU and RAM more is better but you should take you budget into account.

Comment: Since you can't guarantee that "it will do just fine" I would suggest giving SubniC the information needed to make that decision. Personally I've had bad experiences with consumer PC's as business servers. Fried mainboard or fried power-supplies cost us more than a decent redundant server would've cost. Also, I/O may become a bottleneck on consumer hardware, when running all the services SubniC mentions.

Answer (score 0):

I've bought few DELL T110 QC, these machines are very cheap in Poland, and have good parameters (for small companies).
But if You looking for really cheap solution the best way will be buy components and build machine from the scratch :).